# Align reCaptcha to right on Contact Form 7

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7, captcha

I am running a wordpress site with contact form 7. I have signed up to reCaptcha and everything is working fine except all the fields on the form are right aligned but the reCaptcha is aligned to the left.

Is there anyway to align it to the right like the rest of the fields?

Heres a screenshot from my local machine:
[image: Picture of reCaptcha aligning to left on contact form 7]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that directly inside the CF7 plugin you need to modify the CSS.

Add the following to your theme's *style.css* file:

```
.wpcf7-recaptcha > div {
    margin: 0 0 15px auto;
}
```

PLEASE BE NOTED:

If you add the above code, it will take effect to all your recaptcha fields in every forms on your website.

Often times, we would like to only do this to a certain form, this is how you can do it:

First: Add an ID to the recaptcha in Contact Form 7

```
[recaptcha id:enquiryFormRecaptcha]
```

Second: Customize your CSS

```
#enquiryFormRecaptcha > div {
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
```

Good luck!